# How to print specific lines that only satisfies condition in Linux? (Bash Scripting)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have txt file which is seperated with comma to columns. I found number of fields in each line with

> ```
> numfields=`awk -F ',' '{print NF}' $1`
> ```

and output is be like

> ```
> 5
> 5
> 6
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 6
> ```

I need to print first field (cut -f1 ",") of workers.txt which lines have equal and more than 6 fields.

Thanks in advance

Workers file contains data about workers name, positions (can be multiple, and I'm trying to find which workers have more than 3 positions), shift and working hours, seperated with comma.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `awk -F, 'NF >= 6 { print $1 }' workers.txt` if I understand what you're looking for correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F , 'NF>=6 {print $1}' workers.txt
```

Awk programs are a list of condition and action pairs, which process each record (line). Here the condition is `NF>=6`. If a line meets that condition, the action is `print $1` (print field 1).